# Switch resets when app is closed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I put a switch into my settings view in my app, and have it defaulted to the OFF position. I noticed that if you switch it to ON, close the app and then open it again, the switch is reset back to OFF. I'm not sure if it's something wrong with the code, or if I'm missing something. Here is the code pertaining to the switch in the viewcontroller.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
if (kScheduleLocalNotifications) {
    if ([Singletons getBoolForKey:kLocalNotificationsEnabled]) {
        _weeklyReminderSwitch.on = NO;
    } else {
        _weeklyReminderSwitch.on = NO;
    }
    _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 510.0);
} else {
    _weeklyReminderSwitchView.hidden = YES;
    CGRect versionLabelRect = _versionLabel.frame;
    versionLabelRect.origin.y = 431.0;
    _versionLabel.frame = versionLabelRect;
    _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 455.0);
}
```

}

If I run the IF statement above as NO/YES it still has the same behavior. If I run it as YES/NO it is on by default, but if the user switches it off it stays in the OFF position.

```
- (IBAction)weeklyReminderSwitchChanged:(id)sender {

if ([Singletons getBoolForKey:kLocalNotificationsEnabled]) {
    [Singletons setBoolForKey:kLocalNotificationsEnabled :NO];
    [_weeklyReminderSwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
} else {
    [Singletons setBoolForKey:kLocalNotificationsEnabled :YES];
    [_weeklyReminderSwitch setOn:YES animated:YES];
}
```

}

Comment: Is Singletons a wrapper around NSUserDefaults?

Comment: BTW, I dont know if its a typo but you need _weeklyReminderSwitch.on = [Singletons getBoolForKey:kLocalNotificationsEnabled]. You are setting it to NO both in if & else.

Answer (score 3):

You set switch state to 'off' in both branches of your if statement:

```
 _weeklyReminderSwitch.on = NO;
```

One of them should be YES.

Personally I think it would be more readable and less error-prone to assign the value directly to switch, like:

```
_weeklyReminderSwitch.on = [Singletons getBoolForKey:kLocalNotificationsEnabled];
```